Error loading msvcr120.dll (ErrorCode: 193) - SqlServerTypes on Parallels Apple M1 Chip
I am running Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 11 using Parallels Desktop on my MacBook Pro 2021 with M1 Chip.
I recently migrated from my old MacBook Pro which with an old chip (not M1) where everything worked fine.
Now I am getting an error that msvcr120.dll cannot be loaded:

I already tried reinstalling VC++ Redist.
Where can I find msvcr120.dll compiled for ARM architecture to include it in my project in order to fix this error?

Adding a comment for support. I'm also looking for a solution to this. If I find anything I'll add an answer here.
